# Sending Base64 Image Data to Node/Express Backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, azure, express

**Objective:** To successfully pass the BASE64 image data to my node/express backend so that I may upload it to Microsoft Azure storage.

**Issue:** Does not hit the endpoint when sending image data, the catch block indicates the image was not uploaded, and the console.log does not get logged. When I send just the file extension the endpoint is successfully hit (*console logs user obj*). To my understanding, I need to upload the image BASE64 data to Azure to use throughout the app.

**Stack:**

- React-Native (^0.54.0)
- Node/Express
- Microsoft Azure Storage
- Postgres(sequelize": "^4.33.2)

I am using **'react-native-image-picker'** to access the users camera, the photo object that gets returned looks like the following:

```
Object {isVertical: false, origURL: "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=ED7AC36B-A150-4C38-BB8C-B6D696F4F2ED&ext=JPG", longitude: -19.5112, data: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAA…paLbTp1up3fnf8jjajOztyvlV0ldN23+NWvpoklpsr2P/2Q==", fileName: "IMG_0005.JPG"…}
  data:(...)
  fileName:(...)
  fileSize:(...)
  height:(...)
  isVertical:(...)
  latitude:(...)
  longitude:(...)
  origURL:(...)
  timestamp:(...)
  uri:(...)
  width:(...)
```

The data field contains the BASE64 image data that I believe I need to pass to my backend, in order to upload it to my Azure storage. Below is the client function that SHOULD send the appropriate data to the backend.

```
  export function uploadUserPhoto(photoData, photoExt, id) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(authProgress());
      axios.patch(`${API_URL}/users/upload_profile_photo/${id}`, {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'image/jpeg',
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
        },
          user: {
              imageData: photoData,
              imageFileName: photoExt
          }
      })
      .then(response => {
          dispatch({type: USER_PHOTO_UPLOAD, payload: response.data});
          Actions.Profile()
          Alert.alert("Upload success!");
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({ type: USER_PHOTO_UPLOAD_FAILED, payload: error });
        Alert.alert("Upload failed! Please try again!");
      });
  };
}
```

I can confirm that photoData, photoExt is successfully being passed into the function with the image data and file name. The node-side looks like the following:

```
router.patch('/upload_profile_photo/:id', async(req, res) => {
console.log(req.body.user)
const paths = await profilePicUpload(req.body.user, req.params.id );
    await models.User.update({image: paths },                     
    { where : {id: req.params.id} });
    const userInfo = await models.User.findById(req.params.id);
    try {
        res.send(userInfo)
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

Any suggestions? I have looked at using **new FormData()** but with no luck. Reading other posts, some indicate a header issue but I do not see how that would be the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you configured `multer`? https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just stumbled on multer, I am using it now to try to fix the issue.